# How to process sharepoint page (site pages) data returned from rest api, i.e fetch title comments likes etc ,

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, search-api, sitepages

How to process the html(ish) content returned by rest API while fetching site pages from Sharepoint , and  is there any better approach to fetch page data.
Trying the same with search api fetches results but it truncates string which are lengthy..

example the value of key description returns this value :-

The Group of Ministers which is overseeing the issue has decided not to resume the sealing of unauthorised commercial establishments until Monday. The decision came after seeing the current tense situation in New Delhi . The Group of Ministers is he…

instead of ellipsis , i'd prefer the whole string..

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you more